# Could not install module (runpy issue)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, qualcomm, runpy

When trying to install a Python module on the Qualcomm® QCS610, some error messages occur. Python3 is used and the following commands are tried:

**Python3 -m pip install tensorflow**

**python3 -m pip install tflite **

The same error message comes up no matter what module is tried to install:

**"Could not import runpy module**

**ImportError: No module named 'runpy'"**

I thought ,I don't have access to the internet with myboard and assume Python wants to download the module over the internet. So I have found a way to download a module from My PC and then transfer it to the board using WinSCP and then install it from there as well.

I download the module "tflite-runtime" and keep it in Root .

By using **" python3 -m pip install tflite_runtime-2.7.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl -f ./ --no-index"**

By using this command , "tflite-runtime" module should have be installed ,however still showing same errros.

**" Could not import runpy module**

**ImportError: No module named 'runpy'"**

If anyone has an idea to solve this problem I appreciate it.

Thanks.

Deniz

Comment: Hi ! I think it's an environmental issue. Changing  the path of python or trying installation in a fresh environment will give better results. Attaching relevant threads for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46639591/11530462            https://developer.qualcomm.com/project/object-detection-tensorflow-lite